# What should aria-activedescendant be if there is no appropriate element?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

The documentation I can find on aria-activedescendant ([link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-activedescendant), [link 2](https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-activedescendant-properties/)) explains that it may be used to reference the currently-selected option in my synthetic combo box control. However, under some circumstances there is no ID it can sensibly be given; for example:

- The user is not using the control right now
- The minimum number of characters has not been entered
- The user has entered a long search string that doesn't match any options, so there are no suggestions

What should the value of aria-activedescendant be in this case?

- It should be some special placeholder value
- It should be the empty string
- The attribute should be absent entirely (I hope it's not this, because this would be a pain in the ass to special-case in Razor syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the specification is not very explicit on this.

> Authors **MUST** ensure […] when setting the value of `aria-activedescendant` on an element with DOM focus:
>
> 1. The value of `aria-activedescendant` refers to an owned element.

This gives you the liberty to set the attribute to anything else, while the combobox is not focused.

For some practical guidance, you can also check the [Select-Only Combobox Example on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/examples/combobox-select-only/).

It provides an example that uses `aria-activedescendant`, and they mention:

> If the combobox is collapsed and the user types printable characters, the listbox is displayed and receives accessibility focus via aria-activedescendant.

With the listbox invisible, they set `aria-activedescendant=""` to the empty string.

In their example, they additionally mark the selected option with `aria-selected`, because focus navigation is independent of the selection. You need to press another key (<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to select the active descendant.

This is explained in [Focus VS Selection and the Perception of Dual Focus](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#focusvsselectionandtheperceptionofdualfocus)

It is possible to combine focus and selection, for which the ARIA standard allows user agents to apply an implicit `aria-selected` for the option referred to by `aria-activedescendant`.

In any case, the selected option and [focus need to be visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html).

---

Since you posted some sources, it might be appropriate to warn you of some pretty important shortcomings of the example code in link 2:

1. The input has no label
2. It has no value
3. `aria-expanded` needs to be used on the controlling element, i.e. the `<input role="combobox">`, and not on the `listbox`
4. It falls short of providing information that would allow for CSS rules to make the focus visible

It’s also weird that `aria-autocomplete="list"` is set, while the input is `readonly`, and therefore cannot provide any auto completion.

So here is a corrected version:

```html
<label>Combobox
  <input type="text" aria-activedescendant="cb1-opt6" aria-readonly="true" aria-owns="cb1-list" aria-autocomplete="list" role="combobox" id="cb1-edit" value="California">
</label>

<ul role="listbox" id="cb1-list">
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt1">Alabama</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt2">Alaska</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt3">American Samoa</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt4">Arizona</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt5">Arkansas</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt6" class="active">California</li>
  <li role="option" id="cb1-opt7">Colorado</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A future version of the aria spec will clarify what should happen with "late mounted" id references. Discussion is here: https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1970 As the discussion indicates, if you want to make it really explicit that a combobox is awaiting input (and therefore does not point to any results yet) you can post `aria-busy="true"` on the combobox today.

Comment: Interesting. Is busy treated by screen readers? It seems that [only Jaws supports it](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-busy_attribute), is that information up to date?

Comment: it's bleeding edge! AT support is scant, as you say, but the discussion is about drafting text for the next version of the spec. If the spec formally recommends using `aria-busy` in this context, there's a better chance the AT vendors will implement it. There's often a chicken-and-egg problem with ARIA support, and here's a clear case where we can push things forward without causing any harm.